# Cordova android - How to replace custom build.gradle with generated

Tags: android, cordova, build.gradle, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

I have a cordova project, I have added android platform in it. Now I need to use my build.gradle file instead of the one generated.

In the plugins.xml, I have the below code to do that.

```
<framework src="src/android/build.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
```

But while adding plugin, this build.gradle has been put under the package.It looks like this.

```
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
apply from: "com.test.Name/Name-build.gradle"
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END
```

And I am getting below error in the build.gradle generated.

```
Error:(89, 0) Cannot convert relative path libs to an absolute file.
```

I need my custom build.gradle replace the auto generated. Please tell me how to specify this in plugin.xml
The cordova version I use is 6.1.1

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following excerpt from official cordova documentation should help you,

**Extending build.gradle**

> If you need to customize build.gradle, rather than edit it directly, you should create a sibling file named build-extras.gradle. This file will be included by the main build.gradle when present. This file must be placed in the `app` folder of the android platform directory (/platforms/android/app), so it is recommended that you copy it over via a script attached to the before_build hook.

**Here's an example:**

```
// Example build-extras.gradle
// This file is included at the beginning of `build.gradle`
ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = '../../android-debug-keys.properties'

// When set, this function allows code to run at the end of `build.gradle`
ext.postBuildExtras = {
    android.buildTypes.debug.applicationIdSuffix = '.debug'
}
```

Note that plugins can also include build-extras.gradle files via:

```
<framework src="some.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference"/>
```

Check out the [offical cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#configuring-gradle) for more info. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried doing this with ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion but it doesn't seem to be working.  Is there anyway to determine if it's picking up?

Comment: @darewreck try placing file in `platforms/android/app` subfolder (see [my PR for cordova-docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-docs/pull/810))

Comment: I need move maven repository to the first place in all the 3 build.gradle present in cordova android. It can be done extending the build.gradle file?

Comment: @JoseNobile Could you please elaborate your problem? Not able to get your prob.

Comment: @JoseNobile I guess it should be possible by the initial look.

Comment: @JoseNobile I have the same problem. Is it possible to update the generated build.gradle? Otherwise everytime I add platforms, I have to manually edit the build.gradle files. How did you resolve your issue?

Comment: @Gandhi where to put if I am using Cordova 6? No app directory

Answer (score 0):

Set a custom gradle file by placing a file called `gradle.properties` in your Android platform folder (under `<your-project>/platforms/android/app/gradle.properties`) and setting the properties in it like so:

```
 # In <your-project>/platforms/android/app/gradle.properties
 cdvMinSdkVersion=20
```

However, you can replace individual gradle properties by setting environment variables like so:

```
 $ export ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_cdvMinSdkVersion=20
 $ cordova build android
```

Or by using the --gradleArg flag in your Cordova build or run commands, like so:

```
 $ cordova run android -- --gradleArg=-PcdvMinSdkVersion=20
```

You can also extend build.gradle via a build-extras.gradle file and setting the property like so:

```
 // In <your-project>/platforms/android/app/build-extras.gradle
 ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = 20
```